# Dirtychange change event in a formpanel

Tags: events, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a formpanel, which displays information after clicking on a company in my grid.
this is the handler for my clickevent on the grid:

```
var onCompanyGridClickHandler = function (grid, rec) {


            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: '../GetCompany',
                params: { id: rec.get('id') },
                success: function (res) {
                    //Fill Fields with values
                    companyFormValues = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                    companyInfoFormPanel.getForm().setValues(companyFormValues);
                }
            });

  };
```

So everytime I click on the grid, the form gets new values.
How can I implement a dirty change listener, which reminds me, when I changed a form value, to save the changes.

I tried to fire the isdirty on a beforeclick event on the grid, but it didn't work, and all I get is a dirtychange on every form that changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
var onCompanyGridClickHandler = function (grid, rec) {
        form = companyInfoFormPanel.getForm();
        if(!form.isDirty()){
            Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: '../GetCompany',
            params: { id: rec.get('id') },
            success: function (res) {
                //Fill Fields with values
                companyFormValues = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                companyInfoFormPanel.getForm().setValues(companyFormValues);
            }
          });
        }
        else{
          Ext.Msg.alert("Warning", "Please save the data!!")
        }
       };
```

Simple [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devd/bMwaH/76/) for reference.

**Was missing trackResetOnLoad:true**

Updated Fiddle : [Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/devd/bMwaH/76/)

Comment: Still the same problem. Without changing the formfields, i receive the alert.

Comment: @tritrotrash,Its working check the updated answer.:-)